# MySQL REGEXP Y-m-d with multiple months

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm storing some data in a field called `published`. I need to use a regular expression to match the format of `Y-m-d`. Y and d can be excluded, however i need to any value in array of 3 months like `$months = ['01,'02','03]`. i need to match any of the 3 months in my regular expression this is my regex so far:

`$regex = '^([0-9]{4}\-'.$months.'\-[0-9]{2})$';`

I'm unsure on what the syntax would be for the months. would it be like `01|02|03`? i'm not very good with regular expressions yet.

**Updated**

I found the following regex which will match:
`^([0-9]{4}\-{1}(05|01|03){1}\-{1}[0-9]{2})$` not sure if its compatible with mysql but i'm going to try and see what happens. http://regexr.com/3c440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FrankerZ answer works, however for our purposes the field can store any type of text, not just a `Y-m-d` formatted date. This query is intended to target only records with a pattern that matches `Y-m-d` format and all others are simply not cared about for this exercise.

I was able to accomplish it myself with:

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE published REGEXP '^([0-9]{4}\-{1}(05|01|03){1}\-{1}[0-9]{2})$'`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e311/1

Comment: Backslashes are optional before dashes outside of brackets, and the `{1}` is basically redundant. You can get away with a regex that looks like this: [`^([0-9]{4}-(05|01|03)-[0-9]{2})$`](http://regexr.com/3c4iq)

Comment: If you're checking for that exact regex, you still should be using `STR_TO_DATE`. When you provide the format `%Y-%m-%d` and it doesn't fall into that format, it will return `NULL`, and `MONTH(NULL) = NULL` so `NULL` is not in `(1, 3, 5)`

Comment: @FrankerZ it passes all my test cases. function accepts an array of dates which implodes into the or statement of regex.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use:

```
WHERE MONTH(`datefield`) IN(1, 2, 3)
```

It's much easier to work with datetime fields, as it's easier to lookup and parse the format into a readable format MySQL can use.

Searching ranges becomes easy:

```
WHERE `datefield` >= '2015-01-01' AND `datefield` < '2015-04-01'
```

The full list of functions can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), and you can use functions such as [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert to a dateformat.

Comment: will this require to use a date field? i want to use only a text field.

Comment: You can convert the text field to a datetime field on the fly with `STR_TO_DATE`, although you would most likely want to use a datetime field in order to take advantage of indexes.

Comment: i can't use a datetime field for reasons. other types of data can be stored in the field, so it needs to be flexible. i need to use a `varchar` field

Comment: @RickJames that old beloved silver bullet. let's instead create 3 new columns to provide the flexibility the design demands. nevermind the fact that we can do it one column, its a best practice.

Comment: _Most_ date/time requests involve a "range", or can be reformulated into a range.  For _performance_, a range needs a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.  Regexp tests and "MONTH(...) IN ..." require a slow table scan.  Extra columns make the data more bulky, hence slower.